# Getting console data via Regex and PHP

Tags: php, regex, ssh

I want to get some data of an application via SSH output;

```
root@serve:~# eshtr --statuscheck true --trackerid 06897ea6-ed4d-43c4-bf94-ec8643628943
[ESHTR][INTERNALSERVER][StatusChecker] Status: Standby_Mode
Available status: shutdown, reset, reboot, rightmove, leftmove, rebootgps, rebootping, rebootlights, uwpring
Tracker ID: 06897ea6-ed4d-43c4-bf94-ec8643628943
```

Regex: `'/(\bAvailable status: \b)(?!.*\1)/m';`

```
preg_match_all($pattern['availableStatus'], $sshResult, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
if (isset($matches[0])) {
    foreach ($matches[0] as $match) {
        $options = explode(',' $match);
// shutdown
// reset
// reboot
// rightmove
//...
    }
}
```

I want to add it to the `options` in the form structure, but how can I get the status options from the SSH result?

Comment: does the response always arrive in the same 4 line format with the statuses always on line 3?

Comment: More details are coming when the device is active. This increases the number of lines. The statuses can also change depending on the condition and type of the device. @ProfessorAbronsius

Comment: ok . the cited pattern seems to match only the `Available status:` where as `$pttn='/(Available status: )(.*)/m';` matches the data you want (though I'm far from a regex guru )

Comment: Yes, your Regex code works, and **thank you for that**. I hope I can use it reliably @ProfessorAbronsius

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a little tweak to the RegEx and this seems to work fine. The following also filters the results to trim excess whitespace from each status code using `array_walk`

```
    $response='root@serve:~# eshtr --statuscheck true --trackerid 06897ea6-ed4d-43c4-bf94-ec8643628943
        [ESHTR][INTERNALSERVER][StatusChecker] Status: Standby_Mode
        Available status: shutdown, reset, reboot, rightmove, leftmove, rebootgps, rebootping, rebootlights, uwpring
        Tracker ID: 06897ea6-ed4d-43c4-bf94-ec8643628943';


    $pttn='/(Available status: )(.*)/m';
    preg_match( $pttn, $response, $results );
    
    $data=explode( ',', $results[ count( $results )-1 ] );
    array_walk($data,function( &$item ){
        $item=trim( $item );
    });
    
    printf('<pre>%s</pre>',print_r($data,true));
```

Which yields:

```
Array
(
    [0] => shutdown
    [1] => reset
    [2] => reboot
    [3] => rightmove
    [4] => leftmove
    [5] => rebootgps
    [6] => rebootping
    [7] => rebootlights
    [8] => uwpring
)
```